# Meteor: Regarding transform in the collections allow-method

Tags: collections, meteor, transform, transformation

When calling Collection.allow(options), the docs says this about the parameter options.tranform:

> Overrides transform on the Collection. Pass null to disable
>   transformation.

When I pass options.transform=null, the transform given when the collection is created is still used. I interpret the documentation as no transform function at all will be used if options.transform=null.

So, is it the documentation, my interpretation of the documentation or Meteor that should be fixed?

I'm using Meteor 0.6.4.1.

Comment: Have you tried Posts.allow({transform: null}) ? (I'm using 0.6.5.1)

Comment: @Hamal000 Yes, that's exactly what I've done (but the object also has insert/update/remove properties, of course). Are you saying it's working for you? Then they've probably fixed it in an newer release, and my question is answered. Thanks!

Comment: For me it's working inside a find method, I've not tried inside an allow method yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fixed in Meteor 0.7:

> Fix passing transform: null option to collection.allow() to disable
>   transformation in validators. #1659

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/History.md